# Passing property to component using component returned by HOC causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a `DataComponent` component and it is a HOC:

```
const DataComponent = (ComposedComponent, url) => 
class DataComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            loaded: false,
            loading: false
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true});
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({
                data,
                loading: false,
                loaded: true
            }));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="data-component">
                {(this.state.loading) ? 
                    <div>Loading</div> :
                    <ComposedComponent {...this.state}/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then I use `RandomMeUsers` to render that HOC (`PeopleList` is another component):

```
const RandomMeUsers = DataComponent(PeopleList, `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10`);

ReactDOM.render(<RandomMeUsers/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

It works fine, then I pass `count` property to `RandomMeUsers` like this:

```
const RandomMeUsers = ({count}) => DataComponent(PeopleList, `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=${count}`);

ReactDOM.render(<RandomMeUsers count={10}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

When I run it, browser sends me this error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. 
This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. 
Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
in RandomMeUsers
```

What problems does my code have?

Comment: [You shouldn't create HoC inside a render function.](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method) Not that it's the cause of the error, just a thing to avoid.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I will remember that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Treyco explained well why you are getting this error. As an alternative to their answer maybe you can use `count` and `url` like this.

```
const RandomMeUsers = DataComponent(
  PeopleList,
  "https://randomuser.me/api/?results="
);
```

and inside your HOC:

```
fetch(`${url}${this.props.count}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    ....
```

But this logic will be less useful if your `url` needs more parameter in the future. So, instead of passing `url` as an argument to your HOC, maybe you can extract it and place it into your props logic. In this way, you can manipulate your `url` somewhere else and pass it as a prop.

Comment: Thank for your help and your advice!

Answer (score 1):

You converted the result of your HOC into an arrow function. This function will not replace your component's behavior and pass props.

An ugly syntax would be the following :

```
const RandomMeUsers = ({ count }) => DataComponent(PeopleList, `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=${count}`);
const RandomTenUsers = RandomMeUsers({ count: 10 })

ReactDOM.render(<RandomTenUsers />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

And maybe this syntax is correct :

```
ReactDOM.render(RandomMeUsers({ count: 10 }), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but the first syntax causes "Cannot call a class as a function" error, the second syntax causes the same error as my question.